# Jaeger agent unable to connect to collector

Tags: opentracing, jaeger

I have started Jaeger standalone binary on a Linux box and am trying to run Jaeger agent binary on Mac that tries to connect to the Jaeger collector of the standalone process. However it keeps failing with "error":"tchannel error ErrCodeTimeout: timeout".

The problem is not with different OS versions as I get the same error when trying from another Linux box. I used telnet to confirm that the collector port was open for connection.

The stack trace is below-
./cmd/agent/agent- --collector.host-port=172.xx.2.4:14267
{"level":"info","ts":1542954225.5485492,"caller":"tchannel/builder.go:94","msg":"Enabling service discovery","service":"jaeger-collector"}
{"level":"info","ts":1542954225.5489438,"caller":"peerlistmgr/peer_list_mgr.go:111","msg":"Registering active peer","peer":"172.xx.2.4:14267"}
{"level":"info","ts":1542954225.5502574,"caller":"agent/main.go:62","msg":"Starting agent"}
{"level":"info","ts":1542954226.5518098,"caller":"peerlistmgr/peer_list_mgr.go:157","msg":"Not enough connected peers","connected":0,"required":1}
{"level":"info","ts":1542954226.552439,"caller":"peerlistmgr/peer_list_mgr.go:166","msg":"Trying to connect to peer","host:port":"172.xx.2.4:14267"}
{"level":"error","ts":1542954226.8054206,"caller":"peerlistmgr/peer_list_mgr.go:171","msg":"Unable to connect","host:port":"172.xx.2.4:14267","connCheckTimeout":0.25,"error":"tchannel error ErrCodeTimeout: timeout","stacktrace":"github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/pkg/discovery/peerlistmgr.(*PeerListManager).ensureConnections\n\t/Users/swarnim/go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/pkg/discovery/peerlistmgr/peer_list_mgr.go:171\ngithub.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/pkg/discovery/peerlistmgr.(*PeerListManager).maintainConnections\n\t/Users/swarnim/go/src/github.com/jaegertracing/jaeger/pkg/discovery/peerlistmgr/peer_list_mgr.go:101"}